# Summary statistics table for likert data using gtsummary

Tags: r

I am trying to create a summary table for data where participants have been asked to indicate their opinion on a variety of items on a 5 point likert scale. (code to generate sample data at the end). I want to show the frequency of responses for each item and the proportion as a percentage. I would also ideally like to show the average response for each item.

It should look something like this (dummy data, not accurate):

| item | strongly oppose | somewhat oppose | neutral | somewhat support | strongly support | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 (1%) | 8 (1%) | 81(11%) | 277 (37%) | 377(51%) | neutral |
| 2 | 4 (2%)... |  |  |  |  |  |

I am currently using the following code to do this:

```
df %>% select(c(Q1:Q17)) %>% tbl_summary(
 )%>%
   modify_header(label ~ "")%>%
  modify_spanning_header(c("label") ~ "**Support for Items**")%>%
  as_gt()
```

Which works but generates separate summary tables for each of the items, I want to create one table with a column for option and a row for each item as in the example. Any advice would be appreciated.

Code to generate data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  item1 = c('strongly support', 'neutral', 'oppose', 'somewhat oppose', 'somewhat support'),
                  item2 = c('oppose', 'strongly support','somewhat support', 'strongly oppose', 'neutral'),
item3 = c('oppose','oppose','oppose','strongly support','somewhat support'),
item4 = c('oppose','strongly support','oppose','strongly support','somewhat support'),
item5 = c('oppose','strongly oppose','oppose','strongly support','somewhat support'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::pivot_longer()` to make your data long format, then run `gtsummary::tbl_summary()` with `percentage = "row"` (after some cosmetic adjustments using `dplyr::mutate()`):

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(df1, -ID, names_to = "Item") %>%
  mutate(Item = sub("item", "", Item),
         value = tools::toTitleCase(value)) %>%
  tbl_summary(value, 
              include = -ID,
              percent = "row") %>%
  modify_spanning_header(c("label") ~ "**Support for Items**")%>%
  as_gt()
```

[image]